# Wrong synchronization of RMA calls in MPI

Tags: mpi

I am trying to MPIs RMA scheme with Fences. In some cases it works fine, but for systems with multiple nodes I get the following error:

```
Error message: MPI failed with Error_code = 71950898
Wrong synchronization of RMA calls , error stack:
MPI_Rget(176): MPI_Rget(origin_addr=0x2ac7b10, origin_count=1, MPI_INTEGER, target_rank=0, target_disp=0, target_count=1, MPI_INTEGER, win=0xa0000000, request=0x7ffdc1efe634) failed
(unknown)(): Wrong synchronization of RMA calls
Error from PE:0/4
```

This is a schematic of how I setup the code:

```
call MPI_init(..)
CALL MPI_WIN_CREATE(..)
do i =1,10
   MPI_Win_fence(0, handle, err)

   calc_values()
   MPI_Put(values)
   MPI_Put(values)
   MPI_Put(values)

   MPI_Win_fence(0, handle, err)

   MPI_Rget(values, req)
   MPI_WAIT(req)
   do_something(values)

   MPI_Rget(values, req)
   MPI_WAIT(req)
   do_something(values)
enddo
call MPI_finalize()
```

I know that `MPI_Put` is non-blocking. Is it guaranteed, that the MPI_Put is finished after `MPI_Win_fence(0, handle, err)` or do I have to use MPI_RPUT?

What does this error even mean: `Wrong synchronization of RMA calls` ?

How do I fix my communication scheme?

Comment: I have never used the Rput / Rget functions in anger so this is something of a guess. However, I think it may be due to the fact that the standard says that after waiting "If origin_addr points to memory attached to a window, then the data becomes available in the private copy of this window." This means that the public copy might not be updated, which could cause problems for subsequent calls to Rget. Are you placing the result of the get into a window or just local memory? I think it would be much simpler to use Get and complete the calls as you do for Put, i.e. with fences.

Comment: I don't think my previous comment was correct - the synchronisation issue is actually that updates to the public copy might not be available in the private copy, but this is exactly what *is* guaranteed by the wait. I still think that using MPI_Get and fences might be worth trying out.

Comment: Don’t use request-based RMA with anything other than passive target synchronization. It doesn’t make any sense otherwise. I am the reason these functions are in MPI-3 so I know their intended usage ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add the following call as necessary to ensure synchronization (you need to make sure your window(s) are created before putting data in them):

```
MPI_Win_fence(0, window);
```

Please look at the example below ([source](https://www.rookiehpc.com/mpi/docs/mpi_put.php)) and **note that they are making two fence calls.**

```
    // Create the window
    int window_buffer = 0;
    MPI_Win window;
    MPI_Win_create(&window_buffer, sizeof(int), sizeof(int), MPI_INFO_NULL, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &window);
    if(my_rank == 1)
    {
        printf("[MPI process 1] Value in my window_buffer before MPI_Put: %d.\n", window_buffer);
    }
    MPI_Win_fence(0, window);
 
    if(my_rank == 0)
    {
        // Push my value into the first integer in MPI process 1 window
        int my_value = 12345;
        MPI_Put(&my_value, 1, MPI_INT, 1, 0, 1, MPI_INT, window);
        printf("[MPI process 0] I put data %d in MPI process 1 window via MPI_Put.\n", my_value);
    }
 
    // Wait for the MPI_Put issued to complete before going any further
    MPI_Win_fence(0, window);
 
    if(my_rank == 1)
    {
        printf("[MPI process 1] Value in my window_buffer after MPI_Put: %d.\n", window_buffer);
    }
 
    // Destroy the window
    MPI_Win_free(&window);
```